# yum install -y gitlab-ce failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to install gitlab in a docker container.
And My linux version in docker is [centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64]

And we proceeded the installation according to the explanation on the official website of gitlab.
(https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-7)

Other procedures are successful. However, when running

```
sudo EXTERNAL_URL="https://[my domain]yum install-ygitlab-ce
```

there is always no response after the screen below.

```
====================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                 Arch                                 Version                                          Repository                                      Size
====================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 gitlab-ce                               x86_64                               14.0.3-ce.0.el7                                  gitlab_gitlab-ce                               869 M

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 869 M
Installed size: 1.9 G
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/gitlab_gitlab-ce/packages/gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID f27eab47: NOKEY47 MB/s | 857 MB  00:00:00 ETA
Public key for gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed
gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                         | 869 MB  00:00:18
Retrieving key from https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/gpgkey
Importing GPG key 0x51312F3F:
 Userid     : "GitLab B.V. (package repository signing key) <packages@gitlab.com>"
 Fingerprint: f640 3f65 44a3 8863 daa0 b6e0 3f01 618a 5131 2f3f
 From       : https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/gpgkey
Retrieving key from https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/gpgkey/gitlab-gitlab-ce-3D645A26AB9FBD22.pub.gpg
Importing GPG key 0xF27EAB47:
 Userid     : "GitLab, Inc. <support@gitlab.com>"
 Fingerprint: dbef 8977 4ddb 9eb3 7d9f c3a0 3cfc f9ba f27e ab47
 From       : https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/gpgkey/gitlab-gitlab-ce-3D645A26AB9FBD22.pub.gpg
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64
```

And when I exit [ctrl+c], the following message is printed.

```
+exec svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/logrotate
  - change mode from '' to '0755'
  - change owner from '' to 'root'
  - change group from '' to 'root'
* directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/env] action create
  - create new directory /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/env
  - change mode from '' to '0755'
  - change owner from '' to 'root'
  - change group from '' to 'root'
* ruby_block[Delete unmanaged env files for logrotate service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
* template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)
* template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)
* directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control] action create
  - create new directory /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control
  - change mode from '' to '0755'
  - change owner from '' to 'root'
  - change group from '' to 'root'
* template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t] action create
  - create new file /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t
  - update content in file /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t from none to 8fa3fa   --- /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t    2021-07-07 09:37:24.006848178 +0900   +++ /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/.chef-t20210707-481-d9ppkv   2021-07-07 09:37:24.006848178 +0900   @@ -1,3 +1,6 @@   +#!/bin/sh  
+echo "Received TERM from runit, sending to process group (-PID)"   +kill -- -$(cat /opt/gitlab/service/logrotate/supervise/pid)
  - change mode from '' to '0755'
  - change owner from '' to 'root'
  - change group from '' to 'root'
* link[/opt/gitlab/init/logrotate] action create
  - create symlink at /opt/gitlab/init/logrotate to /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv
* file[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
* ruby_block[restart_service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
* ruby_block[reload_log_service] action create   * ruby_block[restart_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)   * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)   * ruby_block[reload_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)   * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate] action create (up to date)   * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/run] action create (up to date)   * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log] action create (up to date)   * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/main] action create (up to date)   * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/config] action create (up to date)   * ruby_block[verify_chown_persisted_on_logrotate] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)   * link[/var/log/gitlab/logrotate/config] action create (up to date)   * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/run] action create (up to date) 
* directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/env] action create (up to date)   * ruby_block[Delete unmanaged env files for logrotate service] action run (skipped due to only_if)   * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)   * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)   * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control] action create (up to date)
* template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t] action create (up to date)   * link[/opt/gitlab/init/logrotate] action create (up to date) 
* file[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)   * directory[/opt/gitlab/service] action create (up to date)   * link[/opt/gitlab/service/logrotate] action create
    - create symlink at /opt/gitlab/service/logrotate to /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate   * ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:238:in `system': Interrupt     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:238:in `run_command'    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:503:in `run_chef'   from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:516:in `reconfigure'    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/upgrade.rb:32:in `block in load_file'     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:197:in `block in add_command'   from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:746:in `run'    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/bin/omnibus-ctl:31:in `<top (required)>'   from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:23:in `load'  from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:23:in `<main>'

    * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action runwarning: %posttrans(gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64) scriptlet failed, signal 2        Non-fatal POSTTRANS scriptlet failure in rpm package gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64

      * ruby_block[restart_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)       * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)       * ruby_block[reload_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)    * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate] action create (up to date)    * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/run] action create (up to date)     * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log] action create (up to date)   
* directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/main] action create (up to date)     * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/config] action create (up to date)      * ruby_block[verify_chown_persisted_on_logrotate] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)       * link[/var/log/gitlab/logrotate/config] action create (up to date)     * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/run] action create (up to date)     * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/env] action create (up to date)    * ruby_block[Delete unmanaged env files for logrotate service] action run (skipped due to only_if)      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)       * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control] action create (up to date)    * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t] action create (up to date)       * link[/opt/gitlab/init/logrotate] action create (up to date)       * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)       * directory[/opt/gitlab/service] action create (up to date)     * link[/opt/gitlab/service/logrotate] action create (up to date)
    * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t] action create
      - create new file /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t
      - update content in file /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t from none to 8fa3fa
      --- /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t    2021-07-07 09:37:24.006848178 +0900
      +++ /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/.chef-t20210707-481-d9ppkv   2021-07-07 09:37:24.006848178 +0900
      @@ -1,3 +1,6 @@
      +#!/bin/sh
      +echo "Received TERM from runit, sending to process group (-PID)"
      +kill -- -$(cat /opt/gitlab/service/logrotate/supervise/pid)
      - change mode from '' to '0755'
      - change owner from '' to 'root'
      - change group from '' to 'root'
    * link[/opt/gitlab/init/logrotate] action create
      - create symlink at /opt/gitlab/init/logrotate to /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv
    * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
    * ruby_block[restart_service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
    * ruby_block[reload_log_service] action create
      * ruby_block[restart_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * ruby_block[reload_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/run] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/main] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/config] action create (up to date)
      * ruby_block[verify_chown_persisted_on_logrotate] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * link[/var/log/gitlab/logrotate/config] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/run] action create (up to date)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/env] action create (up to date)
      * ruby_block[Delete unmanaged env files for logrotate service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control] action create (up to date)
      * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t] action create (up to date)
      * link[/opt/gitlab/init/logrotate] action create (up to date)
      * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
      * directory[/opt/gitlab/service] action create (up to date)
      * link[/opt/gitlab/service/logrotate] action create
        - create symlink at /opt/gitlab/service/logrotate to /opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate
      * ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:238:in `system': Interrupt
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:238:in `run_command'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:503:in `run_chef'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:516:in `reconfigure'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/upgrade.rb:32:in `block in load_file'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:197:in `block in add_command'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:746:in `run'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.6.0/bin/omnibus-ctl:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:23:in `load'
        from /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/omnibus-ctl:23:in `<main>'

        * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action runwarning: %posttrans(gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64) scriptlet failed, signal 2 Non-fatal POSTTRANS scriptlet failure in rpm package gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64

          * ruby_block[restart_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
          * ruby_block[restart_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
          * ruby_block[reload_log_service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
          * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate] action create (up to date)
          * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/run] action create (up to date)
          * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log] action create (up to date)
          * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/main] action create (up to date)
          * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/config] action create (up to date)
          * ruby_block[verify_chown_persisted_on_logrotate] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
          * link[/var/log/gitlab/logrotate/config] action create (up to date)
          * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/log/run] action create (up to date)
          * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/env] action create (up to date)
          * ruby_block[Delete unmanaged env files for logrotate service] action run (skipped due to only_if)
          * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/check] action create (skipped due to only_if)
          * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/finish] action create (skipped due to only_if)
          * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control] action create (up to date)
          * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/control/t] action create (up to date)
          * link[/opt/gitlab/init/logrotate] action create (up to date)
          * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/logrotate/down] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
          * directory[/opt/gitlab/service] action create (up to date)
          * link[/opt/gitlab/service/logrotate] action create (up to date)
          * ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run
```

I thought the clue was in the phrase below, and I looked up a lot of ways.

```
ruby_block[restart_log_service] action runwarning: %posttrans(gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64) scriptlet failed, signal 2
Non-fatal POSTTRANS scriptlet failure in rpm package gitlab-ce-14.0.3-ce.0.el7.x86_64
```

but they all failed, so I'm asking for help.

In the same way, the installation was successful in the same version of physical equipment as the centos7. The error occurred only in the docker container.

Please ask for a good idea!!

Comment: "yum" uses Linux packaging, not Git, to install items, so this has nothing to do with Git. The gitlab tag still applies though, since these are official GitLab installation instructions.

Comment: In the same way, the installation was successful in the same version of physical equipment as the centos7. The error occurred only in the docker container.

Comment: There's an [official gitlab-ce image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce) on Docker Hub. Do you not want to use it?

Comment: @everythx: in that case, it might be more of a docker question, but the existing official image seems like the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! The gitlab docker image pull is also a good second best. However, I wanted to install additional gitlab in the docker container where I built the infrastructure.